# Uri.IsWellFormedUriString needs to be updated?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, uri

I think I might have discovered an error in the Uri.IsWellFormedUriString method, it might be because it only conforms to the [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) and [RFC 2732](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2732.txt) standards and not the newer [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) which makes the two aforementioned obsolete.

What I think happens is that any non us-ascii characters makes it fail, so urls with characters like æ, ø, ö or å in it will make it return false. Since these kind of characters are now allowed ([wikipedia](http://da.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A5n) among others uses them) I think Uri.IsWellFormedUriString should accept them. The regex below is taken from RFC 3986.

What do you think? Should the Uri class be updated?

Anyway here's some sample code which shows the error:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var urls = new []
                           {
                               @"/aaa/bbb/cccd",
                               @"/aaa/bbb/cccæ",
                               @"/aaa/bbb/cccø",
                               @"/aaa/bbb/cccå"
                           };

            var regex = new Regex(@"^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?");

            Debug.WriteLine("");

            foreach (var url in urls)
            {
                if (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(url, UriKind.Relative))
                    Debug.WriteLine(url + " is a wellformed Uri");

                if (regex.IsMatch(url))
                    Debug.WriteLine(url + " passed the Regex");

                Debug.WriteLine("");
            }
}
```

Output:

```
/aaa/bbb/cccd is a wellformed Uri
/aaa/bbb/cccd passed the Regex

/aaa/bbb/cccæ passed the Regex

/aaa/bbb/cccø passed the Regex

/aaa/bbb/cccå passed the Regex
```

Comment: have you read the remarks at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring.aspx?

Comment: Applying `Uri.EscapeUriString` method to each url before `Uri.IsWellFormedUriString`helped for me

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to change you configuration to support the RFC 3986 and RFC 3987.
This is the config you have to make:

```
<configuration>
  <uri>
  <idn enabled="All" />
  <iriParsing enabled="true" />
  </uri>
</configuration>
```

Taken from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx#CodeSnippetContainerCode5

Comment: Well that's embarrassing, I only looked at the documentation for the Uri.IsWellFormedUriString :-) Thanks!

Comment: Your right :-). I havn't been able to make it work though. When I inspect the Uri class on runtime the s_IdnScope and s_IriParsing still has the wrong values and Uri.IsWellFormedUriString still doesn't accept the iri urls.

Comment: @Simon Are you sure that your config is in the right project? It has to be in the calling project

Comment: Yeah I checked, I even used AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile to check which file it used and it was the right one containing the settings.

Comment: @Oskar Have you been able to make it work using the testcode I provided?