# How to enable IDN/IRI Support for URI-Class by code?

Tags: c#, uri, idn

I'm trying to enable the IDN/IRI support for the URI class, because I need the "Uri.IsWellFormedUriString" method on german umlaut-domains (e.g. www.bücher.de).

I found similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/a/6107682/413531 (taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx at "International Resource Identifier Support") but the solution is not working for me. My current app.config file looks something like this:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="..." type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        <!-- ... some sections in here ... -->
        </sectionGroup>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
        <!-- ... some sections in here ... -->
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <userSettings>
        <!-- ... some settings in here ... -->
    </userSettings>
    <applicationSettings>
        <!-- ... some settings in here ... -->
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

when I just add

```
  <uri>
  <idn enabled="All" />
  <iriParsing enabled="true" />
  </uri>
```

as an other child of  at the end, an exception is thrown: ConfigurationErrorsException - {"Das Konfigurationssystem konnte nicht initialisiert werden."}

So I read further in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx an came across

> IRI and IDN processing in the Uri class can also be controlled using
>   the System.Configuration.IriParsingElement,
>   System.Configuration.IdnElement, and System.Configuration.UriSection
>   configuration setting classes. The
>   System.Configuration.IriParsingElement setting enables or disables IRI
>   processing in the Uri class. The System.Configuration.IdnElement
>   setting enables or disables IDN processing in the Uri class. The
>   System.Configuration.IriParsingElement setting also indirectly
>   controls IDN. IRI processing must be enabled for IDN processing to be
>   possible. If IRI processing is disabled, then IDN processing will be
>   set to the default setting where the .NET Framework 2.0 behavior is
>   used for compatibility and IDN names are not used.

Unfortunatly I was not able to find an example for the usage of System.Configuration.IriParsingElement, System.Configuration.IdnElement, and System.Configuration.UriSection. I've no clue how these are used...

So basically, my problem comes down to: I want to enable IDN/IRI support in the URI class, but I can't figure out how to do this. The config-solution is not working for me, so I would like to try it by code, but can't figure out how. Btw. I would also like to know why the config thing isn't working ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution - at least for the app.config part. According to http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nl-NL/netfxnetcom/thread/56a73dbb-c0d4-4cad-876d-83ad74064393 one has to add an additional line in the app.config if a .Net version lower 4.0 is used:

```
<configSections>
  <section name="uri" type="System.Configuration.UriSection, System,
                      Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
                      PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
</configSections>
```

After adding this line, I could also add

```
<uri>
    <idn enabled="All" />
    <iriParsing enabled="true" />
</uri>
```

without getting an error. My complete app.config now looks like this:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="..." type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- ... some sections in here ... -->
        </sectionGroup>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
    <!-- ... some sections in here ... -->
        </sectionGroup>

<!-- ... insert Missing section ... -->

        <section name="uri" type="System.Configuration.UriSection, System,
                      Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
                      PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />

    </configSections>

<!-- ... insert URI settings ... -->

    <uri>
        <idn enabled="All" />
        <iriParsing enabled="true" />
    </uri>

    <userSettings>
    <!-- ... some settings in here ... -->
    </userSettings>
    <applicationSettings>
    <!-- ... some settings in here ... -->
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 8):

This is my solution, tested worked.

Basically, you need to change the value of the static non-public fields of System.Uri:

- s_IdnScope
- s_IriParsing

  ```
  public static bool ToggleIDNIRISupport(bool enable)
  {
      //Important: Try IsWellFormedUriString() once to initialize static fields: s_IdnScope, s_IriParsing
      Uri.IsWellFormedUriString("http://example.com/query=ü", UriKind.Absolute);

      //Get the assembly that contains the class
      Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Uri));
      if (assembly != null)
      {
          //Use the assembly in order to get the type of the class
          Type uriType = assembly.GetType("System.Uri");
          if (uriType != null)
          {
              object idnScope = uriType.InvokeMember("s_IdnScope", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, null, new object[] { });
              if (idnScope != null)
              {
                  if (enable)
                  {
                      uriType.InvokeMember("s_IdnScope", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.SetField | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, null, new object[] { UriIdnScope.All });
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      uriType.InvokeMember("s_IdnScope", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.SetField | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, null, new object[] { UriIdnScope.None });
                  }
              }

              object iriParsing = uriType.InvokeMember("s_IriParsing", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, null, new object[] { });
              if (iriParsing != null)
              {
                  uriType.InvokeMember("s_IriParsing", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.SetField | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, null, new object[] { enable });
              }
          }
      }

      return true;
  }
  ```