# How to extract digits between two fixed strings in Arabic Language?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string in the format:

> خصم **بقيمة** 108 **بتاريخ** 31-01-2021

And I want to replace the digits between the words: بقيمة & بتاريخ with a "?" character.
And keep the digits in the date part of the string

I tried using this Regular Expression: `(?<=بقيمة)(.*?)(?=بتاريخ)`
Which works on https://regex101.com/

But when I implement it in C# in Regex.Replace function, it doesn't have any effect when I use the Arabic words:

```
    e.Row.Cells[3].Text = Regex.Replace(e.Row.Cells[3].Text, "(?<=بقيمة)(.*?)(?=بتاريخ)", "?");
```

But it works if I use Latin letters:

```
    e.Row.Cells[3].Text = Regex.Replace(e.Row.Cells[3].Text, "(?<=X)(.*?)(?=Y)", "?");
```

Is there anyway to make the function work with Arabic characters?
Or is there a better approach I can take to achieve the desired result? For example excluding the date part?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805812/system-uri-drops-unicode-rlm-right-to-left-mark-u200f-character-in-net-4-5/65927071#65927071 I presume the problem is that a hidden right-to-left mark (or other bidirectional control character) is present in the Regex and/or your input string.

Comment: I tried the suggested solution and using the ToggleIDNIRISupport method but it didn't work.

Comment: Of course the ToggleIDNIRISupport method didn't work; it applies only to URI methods which have nothing to do with regex.  I suggested the link to the question above because your problem and the problem in that question may have the same root cause: the use of bidirectional control characters.  It may be possible that the Arabic strings differ in terms of code points (the `char`s in each `string`) in a subtle way.

Comment: [It works](https://ideone.com/a4S9My) fine.

Answer (score -1):

Since the needed digits (without "-"s) are bookended by spaces just use `\s(\d+)\s`.

```
var txt = "خصم بقيمة 108 بتاريخ 12-31-2021";
var pattern = @"\s(\d+)\s";
Console.WriteLine( Regex.Match(txt, pattern).Value ); // 108
```