# Uri.IsWellFormedUriString for relative Hashbang urls compatibility

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, uri, hashbang

In the following tests, why does (only) the last one fail?

```
    [Fact]
    public void IsWellFormedUriString_AbsolutNonHashTagUri_ReturnsTrue()
    {
        Assert.True(Uri.IsWellFormedUriString("http://www.RegularSite.org/Home", UriKind.Absolute));
    }

    [Fact]
    public void IsWellFormedUriString_RelativeNonHashTagUri_ReturnsTrue()
    {
        Assert.True(Uri.IsWellFormedUriString("Home", UriKind.Relative));
    }

    [Fact]
    public void IsWellFormedUriString_AbsolutHashTagUri_ReturnsTrue()
    {
        Assert.True(Uri.IsWellFormedUriString("http://www.w3.org/#!Home", UriKind.Absolute));
    }

    [Fact]
    public void IsWellFormedUriString_RelativeHashTagUri_ReturnsTrue()
    {
        // Fails!
        Assert.True(Uri.IsWellFormedUriString("#!Home", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

**If `Uri` recognizes [Hashbangs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) in the Absolute version of `IsWellFormedUriString`, why not in the Relative version? What am I missing?**

Note: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6107682/687857) doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this isn't working as you'd expect is because a hashbang isn't part of the [URI Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme). The method is expecting the hierarchical part of the URI format and a hash mark (and subsequently a hashbang) is not a member of the hierarchical part from which a relative and absolute path is determined.

< > is a required part
[ ] is an optional part

`<scheme name> : <hierarchical part> [ ? <query> ] [ # <fragment> ]`

as an example of an absolute URI; the query, if I'm not mistaken is ignored, which includes the fragment and hash mark

`http://domain.com/path/to/something/?query=1#fragment`

Here is some more information for you as well. This is all from the MSDN describing the `Uri.IsWellFormedUriString()` method

> Indicates whether the string is well-formed by attempting to construct a URI with the
>   string and ensures that the string does not require further escaping.

Remarks:

> By default, the string is considered well-formed in accordance with [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) and [RFC 2732](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2732.txt). If International Resource Identifiers (IRIs) or Internationalized Domain Name (IDN) parsing is enabled, the string is considered well-formed in accordance with [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) and [RFC 3987](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3987.txt).
>
> The string is considered poorly formed, causing the method to return false, if any of the following conditions occur
>
> The following are some failure examples:
>
> http://www.contoso.com/path???/file name
>   The string is not correctly escaped.
>
> c:\directory\filename
>   The string is an absolute Uri that represents an implicit file Uri.
>
> file://c:/directory/filename
>   The string is an absolute URI that is missing a slash before the path.
>
> http:\host/path/file
>   The string contains unescaped backslashes even if they will be treated as forward slashes
>
> www.contoso.com/path/file 
>   
> The string represents a hierarchical absolute Uri and does not contain "://"

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but according to it - the third test should have failed, and it doesn't. This doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @seldary No, third test would pass because you have `http://www.w3.org/` as an absolute Uri which is enough for it to pass because it detects `#` as the start of a fragment and `!Home` as the fragment text, therefore it passes.